# How to implement multithreading in groovy?

Tags: multithreading, performance, groovy, performance-testing, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to create 10 million customers for performance testing. I am running a basic groovy script for creating a customer with only mandatory attributes. Then I am running the script inside a loop.
How can I improve the performance of this groovy script?
I can't find the corresponding multi-threading options that are available in impex import.
Is there a better way of creating 10 million customers in Hybris?

#### Edit 1:

Sample groovy script for generating customers with different id's.

```
    import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
    import de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.AddressModel
    import de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.CustomerModel

    //Setting only mandatory attributes
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        customerModel = new CustomerModel()
        id = new Random().nextInt(100000000)
        uid = 'TestCustomer_'+id
        customerModel.setUid(uid)
        name = 'Test Customer Name_'+id
        customerModel.setName(name)

        addressModel = new AddressModel()
        addressModel.setOwner(customerModel)
        customerModel.setDefaultPaymentAddress(addressModel)
        customerModel.setDefaultShipmentAddress(addressModel)

        try{
        modelService.save(customerModel)
        }catch(Exception e){
        println('Creation of customer with id = '+uid+' and amway account = '+code+' failed with error : '+e.getMessage())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created multiple `ScriptingJob` with the above *groovy script* and attached them to 30 different `Cronjobs`. Executing all of them in parallel achieved the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the logical answer is to use Impex files. This allows creation bulk and has support for multithreading: https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/44f79c4e604a4bff8456a852e617d261.html

basically you can configure the number of workers or threads:

```
impex.import.workers=4
```

You would be responsible for converting your input format to either *.csv or *.impex

addition:
Regarding the Groovy script, you can set the uid and name with impex, only you would have to provide the random numbers in advance. You could do this in Excel or in some scripting language.

You could even do it in the impex itself with code execution.

But if you just want a lot of random customers: you could also just spin up 10 browser windows with /hac and run the script ten times.

Comment: The problem is that I want to import data with different id's. For example- user1, user2, etc. With impex it is not possible!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you elaborate? Show some groovy script that shows what you are trying to do that cannot be done with impex?

Comment: I have added the sample groovy in the question.

Comment: i have updated the answer with some options and thoughts